# Trigger not firing correctly on import?

Tags: apex, trigger, error, import

So I've written this trigger below. I am having issues with this trigger firing off when I import records. It's meant to reassign Lead owners from querying the system on certain factors, and it works fine inside Salesforce when you update or insert a record. The issue comes up when I try to insert via data loader.

**To be clear, even if i insert one record via dataloader, the trigger does not fire.**

Any insight into this issue would be great, thanks!

```
    trigger LeadReassignmentTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) //after update before insert,
     {
    public Lead LeadRecordName {get;set;}
    public Contact contactInsert {get;set;}
    public QueueSobject Queue {get;set;}
    list<Id> LeadIdList = new list<Id>();
    public Account AccountRecordsName {get;set;}
    public Lead LeadInsert {get;set;}
    public integer Counter {get;set;}

      if(Lead_Trigger_Helper.runonce()){
    for(Lead leads : trigger.new)
    {
      LeadIdList.add(leads.id);

    } 


    try{
                LeadInsert = [SELECT id, 
                              email, 
                              Ownerid 
                              FROM Lead 
                              //where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()
                              where id in : LeadIdList 
                              //limit 1
                             ];
    }
    Catch(Exception e)

    {}
    try{
     contactInsert =        [SELECT email, 
                             Ownerid 
                             FROM Contact 
                             where email =: LeadInsert.email 
                             //limit 1
                             ];

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
//3.3

    //List<Contact> ContactRecords = [SELECT email, Ownerid FROM Contact where id in : LeadIdList];
    /*List<Lead> LeadRecords = [SELECT 
                              email, 
                              Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, 
                              id, 
                              ownerid 
                              FROM Lead 
                              where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()
                              //limit 1
                             ]; */


       // for (Lead LD: LeadRecords){
        for (Lead LD: Trigger.new){
            if(LD.Lead_Lifecycle__c == 'AQL' && LD.email == null){
                if(LD.Lead_Lifecycle__c == 'AQL' && LD.email == contactInsert.email){
                    if(LD.email != null){
     //List<Contact> ContactRecords = [SELECT email FROM Contact];
     //List<Lead> LeadRecords = [SELECT email FROM Lead where email =:ContactRecords.email];
             LD.OwnerId = contactInsert.ownerid;

                }

                 }

           // } 

            }
            //leadrecords.add()
        }

    //update LeadRecords;


//3.3, number 2 FSR 

   /* List<Lead> LeadRecordsName = [SELECT email,
                                  Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, 
                                  id, ownerid, 
                                  Company, 
                                  name 
                                  FROM Lead 
                                  where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()]; */

                Queue =           [SELECT Id,
                                  queue.Name, 
                                  QueueId 
                                  FROM QueueSobject 
                                  WHERE queue.Name = :'VP Queue'
                                  limit 1];
    try{
                 LeadRecordName = [SELECT email, 
                                  Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, 
                                  id, 
                                  ownerid, 
                                  Company, 
                                  name 
                                  FROM Lead 
                                  where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()
                                  //limit 1
                                  ];
    }
          Catch (Exception e)
            {}


     try{
                AccountRecordsName = 
                                  [SELECT id, 
                                  Name, 
                                  ownerid 
                                  FROM Account 
                                  where Name =: LeadRecordName.Company
                                  //limit 1
                                  ];
     }
            Catch (Exception e)
            {}
    try{
                 counter = 
                                 [SELECT 
                                  Count() 
                                  FROM Accountteammember 
                                  where accountid=:AccountRecordsName.id 
                                  ];
    }
    catch (Exception e){}

        //for (Lead LD2: LeadRecordsName){
    for (Lead LD2: Trigger.new){

     //List<Lead> LeadRecordsName = [SELECT email, Lead.Lead_Lifecycle__c, id, ownerid, Company, name FROM Lead where Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
        if(LD2.Company != null && counter != null)
        {
        if(LD2.Company == AccountRecordsName.Name && counter == 1)
        {
            if(LD2.Lead_Lifecycle__c == 'AQL'){

            try{
              Accountteammember AccountTeamMemberInfo = [SELECT 
                                               accountid, 
                                               userid,
                                               TeamMemberRole
                                               from Accountteammember 
                                               where accountid=:AccountRecordsName.id
                                               limit 1];


        LD2.ownerid = AccountTeamMemberInfo.userid;
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }

        if(LD2.Company == AccountRecordsName.Name && counter > 1)
            if(LD2.Lead_Lifecycle__c == 'AQL'){ 
                //&&
        {
                        //try{
             /*  Accountteammember AccountTeamMemberInfo = [SELECT 
                                               accountid, 
                                               userid,
                                               TeamMemberRole
                                               from Accountteammember 
                                               where accountid=:AccountRecordsName.id
                                               ]; */


           // if(AccountTeamMemberInfo.TeamMemberRole == 'FSR')
           // {            
            //Add FSR ISR Logic
            //Finish Query. Test?


                //}             
            //}

             //catch (Exception e){}

            LD2.ownerid = queue.QueueId;

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }


      }


    //3.4, ISR
```

Comment: A few things jump out at me:  
1. Your trigger comment states after update and before insert but your trigger is set to only fire `(after update)`  
2. You do not need to create a set of Ids as the trigger.newMap has the keytset available for you.  
3. You are querying for a single lead record and then a single contact record but not sure why or where you are using that.  
4. Then you are using the keyset to get the lead records but limiting it to 1...  
You might want to take a step back and read more about bulkification & triggers.

Comment: 1. Yes I took those out because I was receiving errors when I was attempting to fix the issue. 2. Thank you for that, I was not aware. 3. The Contact query is to check if there is a contact with the same email as the lead. 4. Thanks for spotting that! I'll go back and change that. I have read some about bulkification and have tried to replicate, however i am fairly new to Apex. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: Unfortunately that will only tell you if it's the same contact as the 1st lead but not the rest of them. I would suggest querying for all contacts then creating a map of email to contact then loop through the leads and use the email to see if the contact exists. What is the business requirement? Is it something that could be accomplished with Process Builder?

Comment: Hrmm..Not sure if it could be accomplished with process builder. Basically for 1 scenario they want a lead to be reassigned if the status is = AQL and if the lead matches an existing contact ID. That lead should be reassigned to the contact owner.

There are more business requirements around account teams and reassigning them, and I'm not sure if process builder could handle that. If it could, that'd be great and I could just use that

Comment: If you're having an issue when you insert records via dataloader, the issue may in part be the sequence in which you're inserting your related records via dataloader (contacts need to be 1st).  If you can't work around that, you may want to add a boolean field (checkbox) that your trigger checks for, that if found to be true, your trigger then ignores the record, allowing dataloaded records to be bypassed.

Comment: Unforutnately, its not that. The records will upload correctly, the trigger just won't fire on all the records. I think that has got to do with what @JennyB mentioned earlier; the trigger probably isn't firing on all the records because of bulkification. I'm making adjustments to it now to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: So, quick update. I have made some modifications to the trigger, but i did some more investigating. It looks like even when i insert 1 single record, the trigger does not fire. Immediately after I update it though, it fires. Any idea whats going on? I understand they should be bulkified, but if I insert one record it should still fire off for that one record...am I mistaken?

Comment: Can you edit your question and update your code?

Comment: Hey @JennyB , I went ahead and updated my code and my question. If you have any insight to the issue that would help a bunch. As stated above, the code works fine when I insert or update a record inside salesforce, but does not fire when a record is imported via dataloader.

Comment: @Christian -- by way of SFSE etiquette - formatting your code better would get you more assistance from the community. It is really hard to read; remove the commented out lines, the blank lines, simpler indenting

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I would suggest:

- Break this down and get one task accomplished at a time even if in a
  developer org or a separate sandbox.
- You do not need to use the getter and setter methods
- Before insert the Id of the lead will not be available so the keyset
  will be null and your leadidlist will not have any ids.
- Eliminate all of your try and catch blocks and let the system handle
  it since you are really just eliminating errors and not handling
  them.
- You are still only grabbing the first email, assuming this is not
  desired to use the 1st email on a lead for all remaining leads being
  inserted.
- Add a system.debug at the beginning of your trigger and you should see that the trigger is indeed running but you are not getting the desired results

I would do suggest doing something like:

1. Create a map of emails to the corresponding lead record.
2. Use the email keyset to query the matching contacts.
3. Create a map of emails to contactOwnerId
4. Reloop through the new leads and check the contact email map to see
   if it contains the lead email and update the ownerid.